# Yahrzeit is most auspicious (source)

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, chabad

An ad, IIRC sponsored by Chabad, in a Jewish magazine (Ami) reads:

> *Chazal* teach us that the day of a *tzadik’s* *yahrtzeit* is a most auspicious day, a יום סגולה ועת רצון, to connect with the *tzadik*, granting us the potential to elicit *brochos* and *yeshuos min hashomayim* in the *zechus* of the *tzadik*.

Does anybody know of such a source from *Chazal*?

Comment: [Don't know who this is, or what he's saying.](https://www.sefaria.org/Chomat_Anakh_on_Ecclesiastes.3.2.1?vhe=Chomat_Anakh,_Jerusalem_1965&lang=he)

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel It’s the [Chida](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) quoting an explanation as to how a righteous person can die on his birth-day if a person’s birthday is a providential day. IAE, it’s certainly not Chazal :)